# Azure AD application permissions: Does permissions assigned to one application will modify another application in same tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-application-settings

I am creating application in Azure AD and assigning following "Application" permissions to that applications.

```
1) Application.ReadWrite.All
2) AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All
3) Files.ReadWrite.All
4) Group.Read.All
5) User.Read.All
6) full_access_as_app
```

I want to know if there is any security risk, if these assigned permissions gives rights to my application to modify any other application.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if these assigned permissions give rights to my application to modify any other application.

Yes, I suppose you add the application permissions of Microsoft Graph, with different application permissions, the app can call different [Microsoft Graph APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).

For example, you give the [`Application.ReadWrite.All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) application permission in MS Graph, then it will be able to call the MS Graph API - [`Update application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), it can modify all the applications in your AAD tenant.

Comment: Okay. I don't want my application to modify other applications in AAD tenant. Is there any solution or can i achieve same thing with different permissions? Thanks.

Comment: @Pooja_2304 I don't understand what is the `same thing` you mean, what's your goal to use `Application.ReadWrite.All`?

Comment: I am assigning Application.ReadWrite.All application permission to perform update operation for that application. But, i don't want anyone to misuse those permission to update other apps in same AAD tenant.

Comment: @Pooja_2304 You mean you want to use this app to update itself? If so, you just need to use `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` instead, and add the service principal of this AD App as an owner to the AD App itself via powershell [`Add-AzureADApplicationOwner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadapplicationowner?view=azureadps-2.0), because the API permission was essentially granted to the service principal, then the service principal of this AD App will just be able to update the AD App itself via MS Graph.

Comment: @Pooja_2304 Note in the command, it should be `Add-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId <objectid of the AD App> -RefObjectId <objectid of the service principal>`, you could not do it in the portal.

Comment: Thanks @Joy. Apologies for delayed response.